# Column items not aligning to center

Tags: flutter

I have a ButtonTheme and an InkWell (inside a Column) not centered.
I tried with CrossAxisAlignment.center a padding left but still not taking it.
Any suggestion?

```
body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[

        ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 300.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text("Sample Text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
            )),

        InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Ink.image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/sampleimg.jpg'),
            width: 280,
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Thanks,

Javier Caceres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your Column widget with  a Center widget

```
body: Center(
      child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[

        ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 300.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text("Sample Text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
            )),

        InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Ink.image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/sampleimg.jpg'),
            width: 280,
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Please tell if it works out!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the Column doesn't have a fixed width or height you can wrap it with a Container and give it the height and the width of the screen.
you can get it by these two lines:

```
final deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

then you can use `center widget` or `crossAxisAlignment` or even `mainAxisAlignment` because now the Column knows the height and the width that it has.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, Nikos for the reply. I didn not have a chance to try this option, I could just try out Nithin´s suggestion above.